# MVC 4 CreateUserAndAccount in combination with azure mobile services

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure-mobile-services

I have a table in Windows Azure Mobile Services, which I want to hold my user account info.
Since the `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` can't handle [schema].[Table] I have made a synonym table with `create synonym dbo.table from mobileservices.table`.

When trying to insert data into this using the CreateUserAndAccount, an exception with Username already exists is thrown.

How can I get around this?

Any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: Does the username already exist?

Comment: haha, valid point, but no :)

Comment: Have you tried querying the table yourself in LINQPad to see what the results show? Might be more telling, hard to know from what you've said.

Comment: It's pretty simple. If I use a blank table with the same entities as in the one from Mobile Services, it's being inserted correctly, if I switch to my "synonym" table, it gets created but then tells me the username already exists :(

Comment: Please provide the exception message you are getting. Maybe that can help narrow it down.